# A regular expression in Visual Studio to do search and replace on this example line?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'd like to replace lines like the following:

```
 Debug.Assert(value == 10.01);
```

with a line like the following:

```
 MyAssert.Equals(value, 10.01);
```

What is the regular expression to perform this, in Visual Studio Studio 2010?

**Clarification**

There is 1000x instances, each with a different first and second parameter. This problem requires some form of search/replace regular expression.

Comment: What have you tried, and which part is causing you problems?  Here's a resource on regular expressions in visual studio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: And here's a tutorial (*edit*: tho partly a product ad - sorry about that.  No I don't recommend that product.  Anyone got a better tutorial?) on how regular expressions work (so the VS reference will help you) - http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Find:

```
Debug.Assert\({[^]*} == {[^)]*}\)
```

Replace With:

```
MyAssert.Equals(\1, \2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace

```
Debug.Assert(value ==
```

with

```
MyAssert.Equals(value,
```

It may not need any regular expression.

So you can use a regular expression. For example,

```
Debug.Assert\((.*) ==
```

and replacement string

```
MyAssert.Equals(\1,
```

Comment: This actually would work, you just do `Debug.Assert(` and `MyAssert.Equals(` and then you'll have some errors to resolve.

Comment: Cheers, I get the basic idea of how it works now. What were you using for your RegEx parser? Visual Studio uses \1 and \2 for the replacement strings, instead of $1 and $2.

Comment: great ... yup some work with $ and some with \. I tested regex on the online site. Not sure for Visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do the following:

Find all `Debug.Assert(<someName> == <someValue>);` and replace this with `MyAssert.Equals(<someName>, <someValue>);`

With a search replace you couldn't keep the `someName`.

I would try it with:

Search: `Debug.Assert\({[\S]+} == {[^)]+}\);`

Replace:`MyAssert.Equals\(\1, \2\);`

But I don't have any Visual Studio (I am on OS X) to try it on :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2012, you use the $ sign to enter a matched group.

E.g.

Find
`.([a-zA-Z]*)XYZ`

Replace
`.$1ABC`

This regex find/replace will replace all the fields suffixed with XYZ and change then to fields suffixed with ABC.